# MySQL Join Multiple IDs From Another Table

Tags: mysql, join

I've spent hours trying to work out how to do this for my project, but I can't seem to find either, a good way of explaining it in order to research the correct thing, or an answer to my question, hence the post here.

---

I have two tables as shown below, one with an ID and the name, and another with fields relating to those IDs. I need to be able to match the ID to the name.

Table 1:

```
ID | Name
---|----------
1  | Square
2  | Rectangle
3  | Circle
```

Table 2:

```
ID | Field1ID | Field1Data | Field2ID | Field2Data | Field3ID | Field3Data
---|----------|------------|----------|------------|----------|-----------
1  | 1        | Red        | 3        | Green      | 2        | Blue
```

I need to be able to match the FieldxID's in table 2 to the name's in table 1 creating the following:

```
ID | Field1ID | Field1Data | Field2ID | Field2Data | Field3ID  | Field3Data
---|----------|------------|----------|------------|-----------|-----------
1  | Square   | Red        | Circle   | Green      | Rectangle | Blue
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Terrible design for table 2, I'm not surprised you have issues working with that table. Fix it first, think about [DB Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: I have to second what Cid said. Table 2 makes no sense. Did you create it? If so, you should redo that part. Make a table with 3 columns: ID, ShapeID and Color.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't, I'd much perfer to do what you've suggested and then just use a standard inner join.

Comment: @Layer8 good luck then, and I mean it. You can try to find the person who designed that and yell at him/her/whatever gender, especially the day you'll realize you need 42 more fields in your aplication

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need  several joins, one for each fieldID

```
select b.Name, a.Field1Data, c.name, a.Field2Data, d.name, a.FieldeData
from table2 a
inner join table1 b on b.id = a.Field1ID
inner join table1 c on c.id = a.Field2ID
inner join table1 d on d.id = a.Field3ID
```